# How to fix an off-centered stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, uistackview

Here I have a horizontal stack view with three subviews, however, it looks to be a bit off-centered as shown below.

[image]

I tried to:

1. Constrain the stack view's centerXAnchor to be equal to the superview's centerXAnchor
2. Set the stack view's alignment to center

How can I correctly align my stack view to the center of the superview?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(macroStackView)
        macroStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        constrainView()
    }
    
    lazy var carbView: UIView = {
        var view = UIView()
        
        var iv = UIImageView(image: Image.planViewBg)
        iv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 105, height: 118)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        var label1 = UILabel()
        label1.text = "31%"
        label1.textAlignment = .center
        
        var label2 = UILabel()
        label2.text = "30g"
        label2.textAlignment = .center
        
        var label3 = UILabel()
        label3.text = "Carbs"
        label3.textAlignment = .center
        
        var labelStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2, label3])
        labelStack.axis = .vertical
        labelStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(iv)
        iv.addSubview(labelStack)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            labelStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerXAnchor),
            labelStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var proteinView: UIView = {
        var view = UIView()
        
        var iv = UIImageView(image: Image.planViewBg)
        iv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 105, height: 118)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        var label1 = UILabel()
        label1.text = "23%"
        label1.textAlignment = .center
        
        var label2 = UILabel()
        label2.text = "23g"
        label2.textAlignment = .center
        
        var label3 = UILabel()
        label3.text = "Protein"
        label3.textAlignment = .center
        
        var labelStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2, label3])
        labelStack.axis = .vertical
        labelStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(iv)
        iv.addSubview(labelStack)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            labelStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerXAnchor),
            labelStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var fatView: UIView = {
        var view = UIView()
        
        var iv = UIImageView(image: Image.planViewBg)
        iv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 105, height: 118)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        var label1 = UILabel()
        label1.text = "46%"
        label1.textAlignment = .center
        
        var label2 = UILabel()
        label2.text = "20g"
        label2.textAlignment = .center
        
        var label3 = UILabel()
        label3.text = "Fat"
        label3.textAlignment = .center
        
        var labelStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2, label3])
        labelStack.axis = .vertical
        labelStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(iv)
        iv.addSubview(labelStack)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            labelStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerXAnchor),
            labelStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var macroStackView: UIStackView = {
        var stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [carbView, proteinView, fatView])
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.alignment = .center
        
        return stack
    }()
    
    func constrainView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            macroStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            macroStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30),
            macroStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,
                                                  multiplier: 0.9)
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tthe `iv`s do not have its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to false. This makes its position fixed at (0, 0) within the `view`s. The `view`s are properly stretched by the stack view however, which is why a frame of (0, 0, 105, 118) leaves a lot of blank space on the right.

The alignment of a stack view describes how things are distributed *perpendicular* to the axis. In this case, the axis is horizontal, so `alignment` is about how things align along the height of the stack view, not the *width* as you may have assumed. It seems like you want `.fill` here - the "boxes" should fill the height of the stack view.

In any case, a simple solution is to position the `iv`s correctly within the `view`s by adding constraints.

You should first set

```
iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

as you are about to add constraints. Then add these constraints:

```
iv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 105),
iv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 118),
iv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
iv.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
```

I also don't see anything that determines the height of `macroStackView`. You should add a height constraint to `macroStackView`.

```
macroStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 118)
```

Alternatively, you could un-embed `iv` from the `view`, and just `return iv` directly.

```
lazy var carbView: UIView = {
    var iv = UIImageView(image: Image.planViewBg)
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    
    var label1 = ...
    var label2 = ...
    var label3 = ...
    
    var labelStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2, label3])
    ...
    iv.addSubview(labelStack)
    
    ...
    
    return iv
}()
```

In this case, you would need to set the `spacing` of the stack view to achieve the spacing that you want.

Comment: I appreciate you helping me identify the missing constraints and pointing out that I could just return iv directly, very helpful! I ended up not using the iv constraints above, and only setting macroStackView's heightAnchor, and aligned the stack view correctly!